# Deserialize generic type not working properly

Tags: c#, json

I'm using the method below to Deserialize a json object .

```
public static T DeserializeJson<T>(string Json)
{
    if (CanDesirialize(Json))
    {
          return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Json);
    }

    return (T)new object();
}
```

and a service method which calls the Deserialize method :

```
public T ExecuteService<T>() 
{
    // call service
    return DeserializeJson<T>(rslt);
}
```

this works fine when i directly pass a type example `People[]` to the desirialize method. but when i called within the service method :

```
var rslt = ExecuteService<People[]>();
```

It does not work:

> Exception "Require an array object"

I tried to catch the T type within the Deserialize Method and checked the IsArray property and it returned false.

For some reason I still didn't find anything wrong in my code.

Comment: "it does not work" - *what* does not work? what is throwing that exception? Is this perhaps your `CanDesirialize` method throwing the error? or is it `JsonConvert`? Is it the `return (T)new object()` getting called because `CanDesirialize` returned `false`? because that cast will **virtually never work** (unless `T` is `object`). Does the json string *actually look like* an array? or to put it succinctly: can you possibly show a minimal repro that we can actually run that demonstrates this?

Comment: @MarcGravell its `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Json);`

Comment: Im calling shenanigans on this one

Comment: @buff OK; now what is `Json` ? is it even remotely array-like?

Comment: the exception is understood it cannot deserialize an json array to an object . but what i couldn't undrstand is way my T which people[] its converted to people

Comment: @MarcGravell the json is an array of People

Comment: Nope. It's a string ;)

Comment: @buff we need to see it to help more; I've posted an example of it working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inherent problem using arrays here. Here is a fully working example extruded from your code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;    
class P {
    static void Main() {
        var obj = new P(@"[ { ""Name"":""Fred"" }, { ""Name"":""Wilma"" } ]");
        var people = obj.ExecuteService<People[]>();
        foreach (var person in people) {
            Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
        }
    }
    public P(string rslt) { this.rslt = rslt; }
    private readonly string rslt;
    public T ExecuteService<T>()
    {
        // call service
        return DeserializeJson<T>(rslt);
    }

    public static T DeserializeJson<T>(string Json)
    {
        if (CanDesirialize(Json))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Json);
        }

        return (T)new object();
    }

    private static bool CanDesirialize(string json) => true;
}
public class People {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So: if your code doesn't work - the problem is almost certainly in your specific json and object-model. Which: we don't have.

Comment: when i Pass Directly the People[] to the method `(var rslt = DeserializeJson<People[]>(json);` It Works . but when i pass the People[] in the Execute method (`Execute<People[]>()` ) with a break-point on the Deserialize method and check the T type it returns People Object (a single object) even tho i passed an array

Comment: @buff please edit your question to include sample code - like the code in my example above - that actually shows this actually happening. Until then, it is pretty much impossible to understand what you've done differently. The problem is in the code that you *haven't posted*.

Comment: @buff note I edited the above to also include usage of `ExecuteService<T>()` from your code; it still works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Only problem with your code is this line:

```
return (T)new object();
```

object cannot be casted to People[]. Instead try this:

```
return default(T);
```